# Is there some algorithm for R/W lock graphs?

Tags: multithreading

Suppose we have resources A,B,C and their dependencies **not cyclic**:

```
B->A
C->A
```

Means B strongly depends on A and C strongly depends on A. For example: B,C is precomputed resources from A. So if A updates, B,C should be updated too. But if B updated - nothing changes except B.

And for the problem: Considering the fact that each node of graph can be accessed for **Read** or **Write** or **Read/Upgrade to Write** in multi-threaded manner, how one supposed to manage locks in such graph? Is there generalization of this problem?

**Update**

Sorry for not clear question. Here is also one very important thing:
If for example A changes and will force B,C to be updated it means that the moment B and their dependencies updates - it will free write lock.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Just put a RW lock on each node? What's the issue? It's even simplier when the graph is not cyclic - deadlocks are impossible, right? And update dependencies lazily, meaning each dependency checks updated date of its parent.

Comment: is this a language/framework independent question?

Comment: Yes it is independent. If it has general solution, then language doesn't really matter.

Comment: Placing a lock on A implies locking B and C. When is each lock being released? Lock is released as soon as possible after the read/write or is kept until all operations in a connected graph are done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a blend of transaction - locking - concurrency - conflict resolution. Therefore models used in relational databases might serve your purpose.

There are many methods defined for [concurrency control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control).

In your case some might apply depending of how optimistic or pessimistic your algorithm needs to be, how many reads or writes, and what is the amount of data per-transaction.

I can think of the two methods that can help in your case:

**1. [Strict Two-Phase Locking (SSPL or S2PL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serializability#Testing_conflict_serializability)**

A transaction begins, `A`, `B`, `C` locks are being obtained and are kept until the end of the transaction. Because multiple locks are kept until the end of the transaction, while acquiring the locks a deadlock condition might be encountered. Locks can change during the transaction time.

This approach is serializable, meaning that all events come in order and no other party can make any changes while the transaction holds.

This approach is pessimistic and locks might hold for a good amount of time, thus resources and time will be spent.

**2. [Multiversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control)**

Instead of placing locks on `A`, `B`, `C`, maintain version numbers and create a snapshot of each. All changes will be done to snapshots. At the end, all snapshots will replace the previous versions. If any version of `A`, `B` and `C`  has changed then an error condition occurs and changes are discarded.

This approach does not place read or write locks meaning that will be fast. But in case of conflicts, if any version has changed in the interim, then data will be discarded.

This is optimistic but might spend much more resources in favor of speed.

[**Transaction log**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_log)

In database systems there is also the concept of "transaction log". This means that any transaction being it completed or pending will be present in the "transaction log". So every operation done in any of the above methods is first done to the transaction log. Operations from the log will be materialized at the right moment in the main store. In case of failures the log is analyzed, completed transactions are materialized to the main store and the pending ones are just discarded.

This is used also in ["log shipping"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_shipping) in order to ship the log to other servers for the purpose of replication.

**Known Implementations**

There are multiple in-memory databases that might prevent some hassle with implementing your own solution.

[H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#transaction_isolation) provides also serializable isolation level that can match your use case.

[go-memdb](https://github.com/hashicorp/go-memdb) provides multiversion concurrency. This one uses an [immutable radix tree algorithm](https://github.com/hashicorp/go-immutable-radix), therefore you can look also into this one for details if you are searching to build your own solution.

Many more are defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_in-memory_databases).

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a specific pattern here; so my solution would go like this:

First of all, I would *reverse* the edges in your graph. You don't care that A is a dependency for B; meaning: the *other* direction is telling you what is required to lock on:

```
A->B
A->C
```

Because now you can say: if I want to do X on A, I need the X lock on A, and any object depending on A.

And now you can go; inspect A, and the objects depending on A; ... and so forth to determine the set of objects you need an X lock on.

Regarding your comment: *Because X in this case is either Read or UpgradedWrite, and if A need Write it doesn't clearly mean that B needs it to.* ... for me that translates to: the whole "graph idea" doesn't help. You see, such a graph is only useful to express such direct relations, such as "if a then b". If there is an edge between A and B, then that means that you would want to treat them "the same way". If you are now saying that your objects might or might not need to be both write locked - what would be the point of this graph then? Because then you end up with a lot of actually independent objects, and sometimes a write to A needs a write lock something else; and sometimes not.

Comment: Well, I thought that it has some specific name to see through paper sheets, but well, your answer just staighted up my thoughts, thanks )

Comment: The problem is: I am a living on the practical side of things. There *might* be scientific papers; or people more into the depths of such topics that know about specific algorithms. In that sense: only having that one tag on your question pretty much limits the number of people looking at your question. And beyond that, you might consider asking this (also; but pointing out the cross post then) on the software engineering site of SE.com

Comment: Well, there is some problems though, Im not clearly understand how Read/UpgradeToWrite will be performed on your solution. Because X in this case is either Read or UpgradedWrite, and if A need Write to change itself it doesn't clearly mean that B needs to perform any actual update.

Comment: I am not sure if that problem can be addressed on such a meta level. I tried to enhance my answer; but my gut feeling is: if you are looking for a really helpful answer, you should decide for a certain language/environment and ask a more specific question, coming with a concrete "example"; good enough to understand this problem in a "real" manifestation.